# D3D9 CubeMap texture

Tags: c++, directx-9

I am making a texture cubemap, and the image is output on all 6 sides. How to print a split image on 6 sides? I want to make it without using shaders and I want to know a site where I can study directX  Are there any sites you can recommend?

this is my code.
ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

```
struct CUBEVERTEX
{
    float x, y, z;
    float tu, tv;
};
void SkyBox::onInit(float scale)
{
    CUBEVERTEX vertice[] =
    {
   {-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
                                  
   { 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
                                  
   {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
                                  
   {-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
                                  
   {-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   {-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
                                  
   { 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f },
   { 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f }
};
m_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(vertice), 0, D3DFVF_CUBEVERTEX, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, 
&m_pVB, 0);

void* pVertice;
m_pVB->Lock(0, sizeof(vertice), &pVertice, 0);
memcpy(pVertice, vertice, sizeof(vertice));
m_pVB->Unlock();
}
void SkyBox::render()
{
D3DXMATRIX matWorld;
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matWorld);

m_pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);
m_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, texture);

m_pd3dDevice->SetStreamSource(0, m_pVB, 0, sizeof(CUBEVERTEX));
m_pd3dDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_CUBEVERTEX);
m_pd3dDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 12);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering a cubemap directly as a skybox in Direct3D 9 is not achievable, especially with a "no shaders" requirement. In Direct3D 9, you need to create the resource as a cubemap to use in environment scenarios, and then create SIX individual 2D textures to render it as a skybox--which means having two copies of each cubemap face in memory.

In Direct3D 10 or later, you can create a resource and then create two shader resource views: One as a cubemap and another resource as a 2D texture array. This results in one copy of each cubemap face in memory. You can then *using shaders* render the individual faces of the 2D texture array on a skybox.

Here's an example implementation using DirectX 12 [Skybox](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Kits/ATGTK/Skybox) that leverages the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/). Same technique will work for Direct3D 11 as long as you require [Direct3D Hardware Feature Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro) 10.0 or better.

> Unless you are specifically using Windows XP, there's no reason you should learn Direct3D 9 at this point. Direct3D 11 is the 'mainstream' graphics API you should look at. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/dx-graphics-overviews) and [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: Hm, aren't there libraries hiding away the differences between different directX versions, OpenGL, etc? Might be preferrable to work with these for having more portable code... Just a short peek at duckduckgo revealed [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dxglwrap/), so the idea at least does not seem to be of outer space ;)

Comment: There are of course numerous libraries, game engines, etc. that abstract the difference between graphics APIs. You are still stuck with the capabilities of the underlying graphics API, driver, and video card. Being able to treat the same graphics resource as both a cubemap and a 2D texture array is not a feature of Direct3D 9 era drivers. DirectX 11 and modern OpenGL can do it, as of course can DirectX 12 and Vulkan. BY DESIGN, *DirectX Tool Kit* does not abstract the differences significantly because it's intended to help teach the underlying version of DirectX.